# Neo4j non-Java frontends

Tags: database, perl, neo4j, frontend

### My situation

I really want to use Neo4j for a webapp I'm writing, but I'm writing the app in perl.
Besides using the [REST API](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-cypher.html), what are my options for prepared statements? Ideally, I don't want to have to do any forking, and I certainly don't want to have to call an external program.

### Why

I'm using prepared statements for security reasons, and a database backend for real-time efficiency + speed + ease of use. As a result, [most of these solutions](http://www.neo4j.org/develop/import) are, at face value, unacceptable for my needs. While I recognize that the `4j` part of `neo4j` means "support outside of Java is probably a pipe dream", I still maintain some hope.

**EDIT:**

(I'll put what I find here.)

So far, I've found:

- [REST::Neo4p](http://neo4j.com/blog/restneo4p-a-perl-ogm/) (which has documentation on prepared statement use [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/REST::Neo4p::Query), if you'd rather not comb through that first link.). It's also worth noting that there's a DBD connector written to run on top of that, [DBD::Neo4p](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Neo4p).

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, I've provisionally decided to use the [DBD connector](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Neo4p) built atop [REST::Neo4p](https://metacpan.org/pod/REST::Neo4p::Query), because it looks easy-to-use and pretty safe. Although it probably isn't as efficient as I'd want it to be, since the returned JSON under the hood will have a bunch of long link strings. And there'll be HTTP headers with each request/response.

So, for right now, I've decided to use this solution. But I'm leaving the answer unaccepted because I would welcome more lightweight alternatives. Unless the JDBC driver uses the REST API under the hood (which I doubt). In which case, I suppose it wouldn't matter, then.

Comment: The JDBC driver uses the transactional http endpoint which is less verbose than the rest API. Afaik REST::Neo4p also has an API for the transactional endpoint.